# jquery filter values according to specific character at specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter a table of part numbers according to a user-defined value at a specific position.

see jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/bagofmilk/wx9F3/12/

The problem is that I'm allowing multiple conditions - not just ONE character at ONE position.

If you take a look at the fiddle you will see I use Table Sorter 2.0 Plugin which works great. But I also created a small table above that with 7 textboxes. Each of these textboxes represents a value of a part number in the table below.

`'data-log'` = if the textbox is null the value is 0, else the value will be 1.
`'data-val'` = the character position in the part number string.

Example: If the user types "07" into item# 2, then the script will need to filter the table where the part number has a "0" at character position 2 in the string, and "7" at character position 3 in the string

Most filters will search the ENTIRE string for a "07", but I need this to be specific to its position.

I also need it so that when the user also types in "L" into item#7 that the script will filter the part numbers where "07" are at char positions 2,3 AND where "L" is at char position 11 in the string.

Here's the main function I'm trying to deal with:

```
$('.modx').keyup(function() {

   //I emtpy the "values" array and "position" array
    arrval = [];
    arrpos = [];

   //Whatever textbox the user types in must indicate there is a value
    $(this).attr('data-log', '1');


   //I create an array of user input values and their positions
    $('.modx').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-log') == 1) {
            arrval.push($(this).val());
            arrpos.push($(this).attr('data-val'));
        } else {}
    });

   /* THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK...Using the "values" array and "position" array, 
      check each part number where all values and positions are true. 
      I CANNOT COME UP WITH THE LOGIC HERE... */

});
```

I might be approaching this completely the wrong way. If so, I'd love to hear any other methods, or if you can think of the logic I could apply at the end of this keyup function that would be awesome too.

[image]

Comment: Strings are `0` indexed comes to mind when reading your question. Means, if you type `07`, `0` is at position `0` not `1`. If that helps?!?

Comment: I added a picture for further clarity. I also edited the character positions I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regex bases solution

Add an additional data-* attribute data-length to the second and 5th modx text fields as shown below

```
<input type='text' data-log='0' data-val='1' tabindex='2' placeholder='03' class='size2 modx' id='item2' data-length="2"/>
....
<input type='text' data-log='0' data-val='7' tabindex='6' placeholder='53'class='size2 modx' id='item6' data-length="2"/>
```

then

```
var $modxs = $('.modx').keyup(function () {
    var string = $modxs.map(function () {
        var value = $.trim(this.value),
            length = $(this).data('length') || 1;
        while (value.length < length) {
            value += '.';
        }
        return value;
    }).get().join('');
    string = string.replace(/(.{3})(.{5})(.{1})/, '$1-$2-$3');
    var regex = new RegExp(string, 'i');
    $('#partNumbers tbody tr').hide().filter(function () {
        return regex.test($.trim($(this).children().first().text()))
    }).show()
});
$('#clearBtn').click(function(){
    $modxs.val('');
    $('#partNumbers tbody tr').show()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aH3a3/)

Comment: Genius...I could kiss you, but that is obviously a figure of speech.

Comment: @bagofmilk hopefully you have understood what is happening & how

Comment: It is not very effective to query the cell text everytime filter runs.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the logic. jQuery's [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function, which seems to be the most practical to use here, works by running a filter function for every result element. When this function returns `true`, the element will be included in the filtered set.

So, in the filter function we need to check whether the value for the actual row (the text value of the first cell in the row in this case) satisfies all the requirements stored in your arrays.

For this, we iterate on `arrpos`. For every value we use [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to extract the relevant part of the examined string (position is the current one from `arrpos`, length is the length of the current `arrval` element) and then compare it to the current value from `arrval`. If they are not equal, the check already failed, so we return `false`. If the for loop finishes running, we are certain we can return `true` (every check was successful).

A simple implementation (not thoroughly tested, just an illustration):

```
   $('#partNumbers tbody tr') //get the rows
       .hide() //hide all of them
       .filter(function () {
            var tValue = $(this).find('td:first').text();
            for (var i = 0, l = arrpos.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (tValue.substr(arrpos[i], arrval[i].length) !== arrval[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        })
           .show(); //show only the filtered ones (for which true was returned)
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wx9F3/19/)